# How to bypass SSL check of URLConnection on Openshift

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl, https, openshift, httpurlconnection

I have found 3 different ways, and only get 1 of them working, in a very ugly way.

I am using Spring MVC to create a REST endpoint on openshift.

Method 1:

```
HostnameVerifier bypassSSl =  new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(bypassSSl);
```

I put this into a `@Bean` inside `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, does not work.

Method 2:

```
new OpenShiftConnectionFactory()
                    .getConnection(id, username, password, host, new ISSLCertificateCallback() {
                                public boolean allowCertificate(X509Certificate[] chain) {
                                        return true;
                                }

                                public boolean allowHostname(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                                        return true;
                                }

} )
```

haven't try this one, don't know where to get OpenShift library jar file.

Method 3

```
HostnameVerifier bypassSSl = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(bypassSSl);
```

add this snippet before every HTTP request, it works, but I think this is a very bad way of doing it.

How should I add this bypass to my spring mvc webapp? is there a suitable event handler where I could hook this up and run exactly once when my webapp fire up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

end up using this class by @mariuszprzydatek
[gist link](https://gist.github.com/mariuszprzydatek/6046279)

and I put it in spring event loop by implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`, and then override `onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent e)`